# Type of Base class pointer pointing to derived class object

Tags: c++, inheritance, typeinfo

Does the type of base class pointer pointing to the derived class object change?

If I have something like:

```
class base{
public:
    int a;
    void doit();
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    int a,b;
    void doit();
}
```

And then I do the following assignment:

```
base *b = new derived;
cout << typeof(b);
```

Will the type of pointer b change to **pointer of derived** or does it stay the same i.e **pointer to base**? and why?

Comment: It should give a compiler error, you have not inherited derived from base class.

Comment: Assuming correct inheritance, type of b should be base, not derived. Because type implies the type of the pointer ( which is base*), not the type of the object to which it points.

Comment: Note that typeof is not standard. Do you mean typeid?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to inherit the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be like this:

```
          class A
          {};

         class B:public A
         {};


         int main()
         {

           A* a= new B();

           cout<<typeid(a).name()<<endl;
        }
```

output: class A* .

Because type implies the type of the pointer ( which is base*), not the type of the object to which it points.